# Change Fonts of a WinForm's controls

Tags: c#, winforms, fonts

I have a main form. On clicking Tools->Options from my app's menu I'm showing another form (OptionsForm) which contains options to change font used by the controls.I'm storing the chosen font in Properties:Settings:Default:some_object. I'm able to retrieve it and update my controls too, but only on clicking of a button on my MainForm.

I tried calling a function written on MainForm from OptionsForm  by instantiating the MainForm to update the control.Font --> not working.

How to make sure that whenever i change the font in Properties:Settings:Default:some_object, all the controls reflect the change ?

Thanks,
Dev

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Locate and expand the "(ApplicationSettings)" property for a control whose font should be affected by this setting in the property grid.
2. Click the "..." button next to the "(PropertyBinding)" sub-property.
3. In the pop-up window, select "New" from the font property's drop-down box.
4. Enter a name like "UserFont" in the "Name" field.
5. Repeat steps 1 through 4 for every control whose font should be affected, except select the same setting you created before instead of selecting "New" in step 3.
6. In your options dialog, make sure you have some control bound to the same setting, and update the font of that control when you change the font for the application.  For example:

---

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (DialogResult.OK == fontDialog1.ShowDialog(this))
    {
        button1.Font = fontDialog1.Font;
    }
}
```

This one line can affect the font of every control in the application because they are all bound to the same application setting now.  Very handy.

**Edit:**
Or you can update the setting directly (instead of updating one of the controls bound to it) with code like this:

```
WindowsFormsApplication1.Properties.Settings.Default.UserFont = fontDialog1.Font;
```

Comment: I'm showing the FontDialog in 2nd form.I cannot access control of 1st Form in my 2nd form.

Comment: You don't need to access the first form -- it happens automatically.  This is code in the second form!

Comment: @Dev I just discovered/remembered that you don't need this setting on each control.  If you simply bind the Font property of the *form* to the same ApplicationSetting value, it will affect all the controls on that form if they have not overridden the font.  This also seems to handle the positioning of the controls better when you do it this way.  If you select a large font, it will automatically reposition the controls.

Comment: BTW, after you have created this setting, you can see it in the list of all applicatopn settings by opening "Settings.settings" under the project's "Properties" folder.

Comment: Just noticed you can also edit the settings directly, which might be clearer when reading the code.  I added an Edit to my answer to demonstrate how.

Answer (score 2):

As per my understanding you want to set a Font for all the controls in a Form in the Form Load.

Try this code.

Form1 -

```
Form2 frm2 = new Form2();
frm2.ShowDialog(this);
```

And in the Form2- Button click

```
Properties.Settings.Default.MyFont = this.Font;
            Properties.Settings.Default.Save();
            (from Control ctrl in this.Owner.Controls
             select ctrl).ToList().ForEach(ctrl => ctrl.Font = Properties.Settings.Default.MyFont);
```

This code will find all the control in the Form and assign the Font.

Comment: I want to change the font after the FormLoad event. Within the same form, i can change at runtime. But, i cannot do it from another form.

Comment: I modified the answer, try it now.